# tableView.reloadData() does not call cellForRowAtindexPath()

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to implement the tableView list where the first row is used to add items to that list

To do that I created two separate classes for the first cell and for the TableView.
[image]

The cell class uses the protocol TextFieldDelegate to pass the entered value to the TableView Class

```
protocol TextFieldDelegate {
    func saveProduct (newProduct: Product)
}

class TextFieldCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var insertProduct: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var insertQuantity: UITextField!
    
    
    var delegate: TextFieldDelegate?
   
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let vc = ListViewController()
        self.delegate = vc
    }

    @IBAction func addButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let newProduct = Product()
        
        if let productText = insertProduct.text{
            newProduct.name = productText
        } else{
            fatalError("Product name is not inserted")
        }
        
        if let quantityText = insertQuantity.text{
            newProduct.quantity = Int(quantityText) ?? 0
        } else{
            fatalError("Product quantity is not inserted")
        }
        
        delegate?.saveProduct(newProduct: newProduct)
        insertProduct.text = ""
        insertQuantity.text = ""
    }
}
```

The TableView class conforms to the mentioned protocol, saves Data to the Realm Database and reloads the Table

```
class ListViewController: UITableViewController, TextFieldDelegate {
    

    let realm = try! Realm()
    var products: Results<Product>?
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        loadProducts()
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - TableView DataSource Methods
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        
        if let numberOfCell = products?.count{
            
            guard numberOfCell == 0 else {
                print("number of rows working - \(numberOfCell)")
                return numberOfCell + 1 }
            return 1
        }
        else {
            return 1
        }
        
    }    

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        print("cell for row started")
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let textCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextCell") as! TextFieldCell
            return textCell
        }
        else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ProductCell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        
            if let item = products?[indexPath.row - 1]{
                cell.textLabel?.text = item.name
                cell.accessoryType = item.checked ? .checkmark : .none
                }
            return cell
            }
    }

    //MARK: - TableView Delegate Methods
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            print("it works")

        }
    
    func loadProducts(){
        products = realm.objects(Product.self)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    


   //MARK: - TextFieldDelegate Method
    func saveProduct(newProduct: Product){
        do{
            try realm.write {
                realm.add(newProduct)
            }
        }catch{
            print("Error saving context in Product \(error)")
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
            }


    @IBAction func refreshButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
    
}
```

The problem appears after I try to add Items from the text fields. The saveProduct() saves items to the database, calls TableView cellForRowAt, and even returns the required value. But the cellForRowAtindexPath() is not called after that.

I tried to create a separate Refresh Button, which just calls the reload Data method, and it works perfectly.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I guess both `realm.objects` and `realm.write` work asynchronously and the data are returned **after** calling `reloadData()`.Please learn how to handle asynchronous data processing.

Comment: `reloadData` is quite disruptive. Where you know only a single row has been added, it is better to call `insertRow`.  Regardless, you don't load the new data from realm into `products` before reloading the table.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank You for the answer! I tried to load data from Realm and print the products just before reloadData(). Print statement showed, that the new item is appended to the array and the return value of numberOfRowsInSection() was increased by 1. Nevertheless the cellForRowAtindexPath() was not called and the view did not updated

Comment: @vadian Thank You, I'll read more about it. Nevertheless, the item can be seen in the database before reloadData(). If I load data from the realm and print the array just before reloadData(), it can be seen that item is appended to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem!

Turns out that it needs to assign the Cell delegate inside the cellForRowAtindexPath() while creating the cell. So I added the line of code here

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let textCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TextCell") as! TextFieldCell
        textCell.delegate = self
        return textCell
    }
```

and deleted the the underlying code from TextFieldCell:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        let vc = ListViewController()
        self.delegate = vc
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete this both lines, you don't need it! 
Because you are using the tableViewController and overrides the class delegate and datasource methods!

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

And what about your new data? you are call "loadProducts()" only once at vieDidLoad?!
Add a listender to you realm products or call "loadProducts()" before calling tableView.reloadData().

try it out.

Comment: I added loadProducts() before tableView.reloadData() and it did not work. P.S. couldn't You exact what did you mean by adding the listener? I'm new in programming, and was not familiar with listeners yet. Thank you!